# System.Net.FTPClient - How to properly stream file

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to use `System.Net.FtpClient` to download some text files from an FTP server.  I am a bit confused as to how I need to handle the stream and then write it to a file.

```
Using ftp = New FtpClient()

        ftp.Host = "ip"
        ftp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "passw")
        ftp.SetWorkingDirectory("/pathToFolder/")
        For Each item In ftp.GetListing(ftp.GetWorkingDirectory())

            Select Case item.Type
                Case FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory
                    MessageBox.Show("Folder: " + item.FullName)
                Case FtpFileSystemObjectType.File
                    MessageBox.Show("File: " + item.FullName)


                                            Using istream As Stream = ftp.OpenRead(item.FullName)

                        ' istream.Position is incremented accordingly to the reads you perform
                        ' istream.Length == file size if the server supports getting the file size
                        ' also note that file size for the same file can vary between ASCII and Binary
                        ' modes and some servers won't even give a file size for ASCII files! It is
                        ' recommended that you stick with Binary and worry about character encodings
                        ' on your end of the connection.

                        Dim fileoutput As New FileStream("C:\Documents and Settings\jasonb\Desktop\Report1.txt", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)

                        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(8 * 1024 - 1) {}
                        Dim len As Integer
                        While (len = istream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0
                            fileoutput.Write(buffer, 0, len)
                        End While


                    End Using


            End Select
        Next


    End Using
```

There must be something I need to do with the stream.  I can see that the stream is at position 0 and the length is something like 126, but what should I be doing to capture the file/contents?  I keep getting blank files output.

:edit:
It seems nothing is being output because len = 0.  Not sure what this means or what I should do...

```
                        While (len = istream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0
                            fileoutput.Write(buffer, 0, len)
                        End While
```

Comment: Have you tried calling fileoutput.Flush?

Comment: I would also suggest that you close and dispose the fileoutput object when you're done with it.

Comment: @Crono the code steps over `While (len = istream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0` , so it never gets to `fileoutput.Write(buffer, 0, len)`, just realized this.  What should I do?

Comment: @Crono I will use using statements for the filestream, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use the ftpclient i use the FTPWebRequest object, works like a charm, and i prefer to chunk the download in 2mb chunks.
Where targetFullUNC is the UNC of the file to the location you want to put the download.
ftpFullURI is the full url to the download file on the ftp

```
 Dim FTPRequest As FtpWebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://" & ftpfullURI)
            With FTPRequest
                .EnableSsl = False
                .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(usn, pwd)
                .KeepAlive = False
                .UseBinary = True
                .UsePassive = True
                .Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
            End With

            RaiseEvent trace(Me, "FTPDownload() logging onto ftp")
            Using FTPResponse As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(FTPRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
                Using responseStream As IO.Stream = FTPResponse.GetResponseStream
                    Using fs As New IO.FileStream(targetfullUNC, IO.FileMode.Create)
                        Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
                        Dim read As Integer = 0
                        RaiseEvent trace(Me, "downloading file " & targetfullUNC)
                        Do
                            read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                            fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                        Loop Until read = 0
                        responseStream.Close()
                        fs.Flush()
                        fs.Close()

                    End Using
                    responseStream.Close()
                End Using
                FTPResponse.Close()
            End Using
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work like a charm.  Also already being a part of the .NET framework without using external dll is a plus.  I think I can go back to targeting .NET4 client profile.

Comment: Wouldn't those be 2kb chunks?

Comment: yes you can adjust it on this line Dim buffer(2047) As Byte

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is creating files with length 0 is because it is never writing any information into the output stream (your fileoutput variable)

As you mentioned in your comments the problem is in the line with the condition

```
 While (len = istream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0
```

That could work in C#, but in VB.NET it does not have the same behavior. I think in VB.NET this line what is actually doing is not assigning the result of *istream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)* to the variable *len* and then comparing that *len* is bigger than 0. Instead it is comparing that len is bigger than 0 but *len* is gonna be 0, so the condition is never *true*

Try the following:

```
Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(8 * 1024 - 1) {}
Dim len As Integer = 0
len = istream.Read(buffer, 0, buf.Length)
While len > 0
  fileoutput.Write(buffer, 0, len)
  len = istream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
End While
```

That way it will actually write something in the file output stream while the input stream reads the next block of bytes.

I hope it helps.