# How to manipulate FTP files?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am a newbie in VB.NET and I am having trouble manipulating FTP files.

What I need is a function to connect to a server, another to list files, another to download files, and another to send an e-mail. I did a lot of research, but what I have so far is not enough.

For the connection I used this:

```
Public Function OpenConnection(ByVal sServer As String, ByVal sUser As String, ByVal sPassword As String) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim requestAs FtpWebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(sServer)
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(sUser, sPassword)
        fwr.KeepAlive = True

      OpenConnection = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        OpenConnection = False
    End Try
End Function
```

How can I confirm that is really connected before changing "OpenConnection" to true?

To list files  I was using this:

```
Public Function GetDirectoryListing(ByVal sFilter As String, ByVal strServidor As String) As cDirList

    Try
        Dim fwr As FtpWebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(strServidor)
        fwr.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "psswd")
        fwr.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory

        Dim sr As New StreamReader(fwr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Dim str As String = sr.ReadLine()

        While Not str Is Nothing
            Console.WriteLine(str)
            str = sr.ReadLine()
        End While

        sr.Close()
        sr = Nothing
        fwr = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

But with this function I am connecting again and didn't want to do that. I want just connect once and stay connected until I finish using the FTP server. Is that possible?

This is not working either and this is the error I'm getting:

> The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.

I am sorry if what I am asking is simple or if you don't understand what I am trying to ask.  As I said before, I am a newbie and English is not my first language.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way but this link might help...  [system-net-ftpclient-how-to-properly-stream-file]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405825/system-net-ftpclient-how-to-properly-stream-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much of a reason to have one function open the connection, just to call another function to get a directory listing. They should really be one function, as I don't know of a way to check if the connection is actually open. Besides, that's what Try/Catch is for.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

    Private sDirectoryList() As String

    'Some method of starting the Connection, Listing, Downloads, etc.
    Private Sub btnFTP_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFTP.Click
        Dim sAddress As String = "ftp://address/"
        Dim sUserName As String = "user"
        Dim sPassword As String = "pass"
        Dim sLocalDirectory As String = "C:\"

        'If the initial connection opens, continue.
        'Although this isn't really necessary. It should be included in the GetDirectoryListing function
        If OpenConnection(sAddress, sUserName, sPassword) Then
            GetDirectoryListing()
            'DownloadAllFiles(sAddress, sUserName, sPassword, sLocalDirectory)
            'SendEmail()
            MessageBox.Show("Done.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function OpenConnection(ByVal sServer As String, ByVal sUser As String, ByVal sPassword As String) As Boolean
        Try
            ftpRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(sServer))
            ftpRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(sUser, sPassword)
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory 'List, not Download
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = True
            ftpRequest.Proxy = Nothing
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = True
            Return True 'True, all worked
        Catch ex As WebException
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to the FTP server. OpenConnection()")
            'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub GetDirectoryListing()
        Try
            'Read the contents of the directory and store it into a string array
            Dim srReader As New StreamReader(ftpRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            sDirectoryList = srReader.ReadToEnd().Split(vbNewLine)

            'Clear the last split vbNewLine
            If sDirectoryList IsNot Nothing Then
                sDirectoryList(sDirectoryList.Length - 1) = ""
            End If

            srReader.Close()
            srReader = Nothing
            ftpRequest = Nothing
        Catch ex As WebException
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to get directory listing. GetDirectoryListing()")
            'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

### Consolidated route:

```
    Private Function ConnectAndGetList(ByVal sServer As String, ByVal sUser As String, ByVal sPassword As String) As Boolean
        Try
            ftpRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(sServer))
            ftpRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(sUser, sPassword)
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory 'List, not Download
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = True
            ftpRequest.Proxy = Nothing
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = True

            'Read the contents of the directory and store it into a string array
            Dim srReader As New StreamReader(ftpRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            sDirectoryList = srReader.ReadToEnd().Split(vbNewLine)

            'Clear the last split vbNewLine
            If sDirectoryList IsNot Nothing Then
                sDirectoryList(sDirectoryList.Length - 1) = ""
            End If

            srReader.Close()
            srReader = Nothing
            ftpRequest = Nothing
        Catch ex As WebException
            MessageBox.Show("Something failed in ConnectAndGetList()")
            'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```

---

If you wanted only *.txt files:

```
For Each sFile As String In sDirectoryList
    'Clear potential whitespace
    sFile = sFile.Trim()

    If sFile.EndsWith(".txt") Then
        'Read the file...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you  so much Keith. This helped me a lot. I know I am asking much, but Do you Know How can I select just the one specific kind of files. For example just the files *.txt.

Comment: Added it at the end. Basically just going through each string in sDirectoryList and check to see if it ends with ".txt". Please note that this might not be the most effective way of doing this, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, these are noob questions.

First, learn about the SCOPE of variables. If you want:

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest
```

..available in other functions within the same class, you need to make it PRIVATE at the class level. Then you can use it in your other functions. You can also pass it around to your methods but that takes a little more knowledge.

As for the second method erroring; take a look at these two line and tell me what's different (other than the variable name):

```
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(sUser, sPassword)
fwr.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "psswd")
```

The second one, which errors, is using "user" as the user name and "pswd" as the password to connect to the FTP server. I would assume these are incorrect.

Comment: Steve. Thank for your answer I look about. On the second example I wasn't using variable but the server username and password.